# Can I add a field of MVoice in List to mutableSetOf() with Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I can use Code A add all id of `MVoice` in a `List` to `val selectedIDs: MutableSet<Int>`.

I think I can simplify it, and add all id of List at one time, but Code B doesn't work, how can I fix it?

**Code A**

```
 val selectedIDs: MutableSet<Int> = mutableSetOf()
   val listVoiceBySort: LiveData<List<MVoice>> =_listVoiceBySort
        
   listVoiceBySort.value?.forEach(){
      selectedIDs.add(it.id)
   }
```

**Code B**

```
   val selectedIDs: MutableSet<Int> = mutableSetOf()
   val listVoiceBySort: LiveData<List<MVoice>> =_listVoiceBySort

   listVoiceBySort.value?.let{
      selectedIDs.addAll(it.id) 
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
val selectedIDs: MutableSet<Int> = mutableSetOf()
val listVoiceBySort: LiveData<List<MVoice>> =_listVoiceBySort

listVoiceBySort.value?.map { it.id }?.let {
    selectedIDs.addAll(it) 
}
```